# Why do p-values from sjPlot's tab_model() and Anova() not match for LMM output?

Tags: r, lme4, p-value, sjplot

I have a question regarding p-value estimations for an lme4 LMM model output:

I compared p-values produced by the functions `tab_model` and `Anova` and they don't seem to match. When I run `Anova`, I get significant results for a fixed effect I don't get significant results for when running `tab_model`. I'm aware computing p-values for LMMs is a controversial topic, but I would like to do this nonetheless.

I ran `tab_model` with both the Wald and the Satterthwaite approximation for the argument `df.method`, and with setting `p.adjust = NULL` so I get uncorrected p-values, but it still produces different p-values than `Anova`.

My code looks like this:

```
tab_model(my_lmm,
          seed = 42,
          show.se = TRUE, 
          show.stat = FALSE,
          show.intercept = FALSE, 
          show.df = FALSE,
          show.re.var = FALSE,
          show.icc = TRUE,
          show.obs = FALSE,
          p.style = "scientific",
          p.threshold = c(0.05),
          p.adjust = NULL,
          df.method = "satterthwaite",
          digits = 6, 
          digits.p = 3)

Anova(my_lmm)
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Merle

Comment: Which package(s) are you using?

Comment: I use "lme4" for lmer() for the LMM, "sjPlot" for tab_model() and "car" for Anova(). And I think for the satterthwaite approximation in tab_model() to work you need the packages "parameters" and "purr". They are all up to date.

Comment: One of my predictors (age) is not centered, so I get warnings telling me "Some predictor variables are on very different scales: consider rescaling". Could this be an issue for some reason?

Comment: For `Anova` (car), p-values are from Wald test and show the effect of the *whole variable* in the model.  For `tab_model` (sjPlot) gives p-values for *each term* in the model.

Comment: May also be that by default, `Anova()` is doing a likelihood ratio test.  Using code from the `lmer` example, if you use `Anova(my_lmm, test.statistic="F")`, you should get the same thing as `tab_model()`.

Comment: Thanks for your help, @DaveArmstrong and @Edward! 

A colleague of mine just suggested running Anova(my_lmm, type = "III"), and then I get the same p-values as in tab_model.

Answer (score 0):

By default, `Anova()` uses `type = "II"`. If you set `type = "III"`, it produces the same results as `tab_model`. So instead of running `Anova(my_lmm)`, the code should look like this: `Anova(my_lmm, type = "III")`.

Here's an explanation concerning these different ANOVA types:
https://md.psych.bio.uni-goettingen.de/mv/unit/lm_cat/lm_cat_unbal_ss_explained.html